# Serve up Static Image Koa.js

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm returning a value in JSON for example in one of my endpoints:

```
{
    "image":"http//devservername/assets/someimage.jpg"
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to statically serve this through Koa.js and not sure if that's going to be in a route or what...

Comment: Have you looked at `koa-static`?

Comment: Yea I have wasn't sure yet if I wanted to use that

Comment: Well, that's what it does for a living, and that's how all the cool boys and girls serve static assets, and it involves adding about two lines to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `http://devservername` and it will link, ofcourse you should use middleware to serve folders.

use `koa-static-folder`

```
import serve from 'koa-static-folder';

serve(__dirname + '/public/');
```

Comment: For this to be an answer, you need to suggest which middleware, and show a bit of how to use it. Also, the presence or absence of the hostname should make no difference.

Comment: crap now I get the error 2015-08-17T16:37:13.584321427Z Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './assets' after we pushed it to our Ubuntu server

Answer (score 4):

Use `koa-static`.

```
npm install --save koa-static

// index.js or whatever
var KoaStatic = require('koa-static');
app.use(KoaStatic('assets'));
```

This will serve a request for `foo.txt` from `assets/foo.txt`. If you want to serve `assets/foo.txt` in response to a request for `assets/foo.txt`, then call `KoaStatic('.')`. That is probably not a good idea, since it will serve anything from the root. Better to create a `public` directory, put an `assets` directory under it, and use `KoaStatic('public')`.

Comment: well it's not working.  I did exactly the above in my app.js then went to the browser and typed http://localhost:8000/assets/background.jpg and I get a not found

Comment: You have to actually read the documentation and set it up correctly. What the above will do is to serve `/assets/foo.txt` in response to a GET on `foo.txt`. If you want to serve `/assets/foo.txt` in response to a GET on `'assets/foo.txt`, then you need to mount the use request on `assets`, OR do something like create a `public/assets` folder and then do `app.use(KoaStatic('public'))`.